# What kind of violin is good for a beginner?

Tags: violin

I am going to be getting a new violin soon, and I was wondering if there is a certain kind I should get. I want it to sound more professional then the 3/4 size I currently have.

Comment: Even the most professional violin will not help you to advance, if it is to large for you. Before having arrived at the full size, investments in more expensive instruments are obviously not attractive due to the limited time frame. What proposes your teacher?

Comment: There are lots of variables - how long have you played- are you big enough, or growing quickly enough to go for a full sized - what budget is available, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing in finding a good sounding violin is the ability to try it before you buy it, and to be able to have other musicians, especially violin players, listen to it.

Here are a few things to think about:

1. Since you mentioned it, I'll talk about violin size first. It
   certainly possible to find a professional sounding 3/4 size violin,
   although you'll have to look harder than you would for a 4/4 size.
   The size violin you use should be determined by your size, not
   anything else. Read
   [When is it okay to move up a violin size?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40635/when-is-it-okay-to-move-up-a-violin-size?rq=1)
   to learn how to determine if you need to move up in size.
2. If you have a teacher, ask them for help. If you don't have a
   teacher, find one to ask for help and to listen to and play any
   instruments you are considering, and maybe come to the shop with
   you. Many teachers will do this for a fee. Having an expert would be
   very beneficial, and could keep you from buying a completely
   inappropriate instrument.
3. What's your price range? Most professionals will have an instrument
   worth at least $3000 (based on many conversations with players). In the classical world, it seems closer to
   $10,000 or $20,000 is usual, and at the other extreme, I once played
   with a professional fiddler who had never payed over $200 for a
   violin. He was also a luthier and knew what to look for to get what
   he wanted, and part of what he wanted was the sound typical of a
   lower quality instrument.  $500-$1000 will last most students for years of improvement.
4. What kind of sound do you want? Since you are a player, this is the
   number one thing you need to determine before putting your money
   down. Play at least half a dozen different instruments in different
   prices ranges before you buy so you have something to compare to. I
   once tested a $3000 instrument that sounded only as good as most
   that only cost $500-$1000. Also, since violins sound different under
   your ear than across the room, have another violin player try it so
   you can hear what it sounds like to your audience. If you can't play yet, ask the sales person to play it. If you are at a violin shop, they will be able to.
5. Find a reputable string shop. Buy from a string specialty shop that
   focuses on selling violins. They will often have an in-house luthier
   who can look over and repair your instruments, and a trade in policy
   where if you buy from them, if you want to upgrade in the future
   they will give you 75%-100% of your current instruments value as a
   trade-in. They will also generally store the instruments more
   carefully and have a wider selection than a more general music shop.
   If there are none near you, in the US, and maybe in other countries,
   there are shops that will let you order over the phone, and will
   mail you instruments to try for a week for a small fee.
6. Make sure your current instrument is well set up and has good
   quality strings. If either of these are bad, fixing them can improve
   your sound as much as spending hundreds more on an instrument.

Everything I'm suggesting takes time, money, or both. Since anything better than a rock bottom student instrument costs at least several hundred dollars, and professional quality costs several thousand, it's worth putting in the effort rather than taking the first instrument that catches you eye or ear.

Also, the single most important thing in how a violin sounds is the skill of the player. A good musician will sound good on an inexpensive instrument, and a bad musician will sound bad on a fabulous one.